# Is it possible to call a complicated query as a stored procedure within a geoprocessing service?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-service, python-toolbox

I need to implement a searching geoprocessing service. 
A part of the query should be very complicated and use oracle text. 
My service should support spatial search too.

1) I am thinking of performing the text query outside of arcgis by calling a sort of stored procedure from my toolbox. Is it possible ? 
2) A solution could be  to construct a python tool that would assemble the sql quey using a range of parameters provided by the user. However I would like to avoid that solution since I dont want my query construction to take place inside the GP service.

Any ideas on what could be more efficient and easier or any alternatives?